# EF Core Code First Oracle - Cannot set nullable an existing colum

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I set an existing property `decimal` to `decimal?`:

```
    public decimal? TotalAmountTTC { get; set; }
```

Then I created a migration with `add-migration`, it generated me this :

```
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<decimal>(
            name: "c0003_total_amount_ttc",
            table: "t0003_transfer_request",
            type: "decimal(13,4)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(decimal),
            oldType: "decimal(13,4)");
```

But after i execute `update-database`, the column is still `not nullable`:

[image]

When i run `script-migration` to check the SQL generated, we can see it clearly doesn't care about the fact my property is now nullable:

```
        ALTER TABLE "t0003_transfer_request" MODIFY "c0003_total_amount_ttc" decimal(13,4)
        /
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Is this a bug?

I've tried to set the `IsRequired(false)` in the mapping, but same result.

```
         builder.Property(tr => tr.TotalAmountTTC).HasColumnName("c0003_total_amount_ttc").IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: If everything else fails simple run `ALTER TABLE "t0003_transfer_request" MODIFY "c0003_total_amount_ttc" NULL;`. It is fairly good possible that such modification are not supported. What would you expect that the tool will do if you change a column from *nullable* to *not nullable*?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I don't want to mess with the whole CI/CD, and keep a single SQL query to update this column.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I don't understand your question

Comment: The first was non ment as a *recomendation*, but as a *workaround*. The question concerns the *opposite scenario* - you have a nullable column and wants to change it in a *non-nullable* column. Here you must *mess* with the data - provide some *default* value before the column definition can be modified. Here *exists no simple tool solution*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like a **hack** to me, but I've found a way to make `NULLABLE` a column which already exists as `NOT NULL` :

You need to include the `NULL` in the datatype (in my case : `decimal(13,4) NULL`) :

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TransferRequest> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(tr => tr.TotalAmountTTC).HasColumnType("decimal(13,4) NULL");
    }
```